# How to Display Emojis in Laravel Nova

Tags: php, emoji, laravel-nova, charset

In Laravel Nova, I am trying to save User Feedback Emojis in the Database using its decimal value then display it in the dashboard.

But only the Decimal value is displayed not the Emoji Icon.

Eg. , ,

Is this possible in Nova? Or does it need to use a Third-party Library?

Here's my code:

```
public function fields(Request $request) {
  return [
    Text::make('Name', 'name')->sortable(),
    Text::make('Icon', 'icon')->sortable(),
  ];
}
```

***EDIT:***
I am saving the actual characters in the database. I figured out that
`&` is changed to `&amp;`

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: _“I already tried changing charset from utf-8 to utf8mb4 but still no luck”_ - no _point_. If you are not storing the actual characters, then _character encoding_ doesn’t come into play either. _“But only the Decimal value is displayed not the Emoji Icon.”_ - looks like that’s probably because you applied HTML escaping to what already was HTML code.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope this further explained my problem.

Comment: _“I am saving the actual characters in the database. I figured out that & is changed to &amp;”_ - if you _were_ storing the actual emoji characters, then why would there _be_ any `&` to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer to my question.

Using php [`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) fixed my problem.

```
public function fields(Request $request) {
  return [
    Text::make('Name', 'name')->sortable(),
    Text::make('Icon', function() {
      return html_entity_decode($this->icon);
    })->sortable(),
  ];
}
```

[image]